# What’s this yellow rectangular part with a coil, found in a flatscreen TV?

Tags: identification, components

I came across this part while taking apart an old flatscreen TV that no longer works. In the middle behind the yellow tape there seems to be a copper coil. I’m guessing it might be an inductor, but they are generally round.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

[Full size image](https://files.catbox.moe/n05itj.jpg)

Comment: looks like some type of an inductor to me ... looks like it has only two leads ... large image size is not an advantage if the image is unclear

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like a transformer or common-mode choke out of a flat-screen television set. It will likely be a bespoke design for that particular model line.

Similar to this one (image from [here](https://izi.ua/p-53535291-cv338h-t50-main-plata-televizor-elenberg-55df5040):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that’s the exact same board!